# error: no matching function call for call to - compiles with VS2013 though

Tags: c++

I'm writing a piece of code that's supposed to run on multiple platforms. I got the code working when compiling with Visual Studio 2013 with no problems, but now that I try to compile it for Android, I get the error mentioned in the title.

The code I'm trying to compile is like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class StringUtils
{
public:
    static std::string readFile(const std::string& filename);
    static std::string& trimStart(std::string& s);
    static std::string& trimEnd(std::string& s);
    static std::string& trim(std::string& s);
};
```

The methods above are mentioned in the error. As an example, I try to call the `trim()` method like this:

```
std::string TRData::readValue(std::ifstream& ifs)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(ifs, line);
    int colon = line.find_first_of(':');
    assert(colon != std::string::npos);
    return StringUtils::trim(line.substr(colon + 1));
}
```

The error message points to the last line in this method. How can I fix this problem? As I said, it compiles with VS2013 but not for Android using the default NDK toolchain.

EDIT: Forgot to paste the exact error message, here it is:

```
error : no matching function for call to 'StringUtils::trim(std::basic_string<char>)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your function signature to

```
static std::string& trim(const std::string& s); 
                      // ^^^^^
```

to pass rvalues (like the temporary returned from `substr()`) to your function.

Also just passing the value through wouldn't work this way anymore

```
static std::string trim(const std::string& s); 
               // ^ remove the reference
```

I'd recommend to do so for your other functions analogous.

---

Alternatively use an lvalue to call your function

```
std::string part = line.substr(colon + 1);
return StringUtils::trim(part);
```